# ejabberdctl dump errors with "Too short cookie string"

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

When trying to run this command on Ejabberd 2.1.5-3 with Erlang R14A

`ejabberdctl dump /tmp/ejabberd1.text`

to dump the registered users from ejabberd I receive

`{error_logger,{{2012,5,17},{17,9,48}},"Too short cookie string",[]}
{error_logger,{{2012,5,17},{17,9,48}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{auth,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.19.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{"Too short cookie string",[{auth,init_cookie,0},{auth,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]},[{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.9.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.17.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,24},{reductions,871}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2012,5,17},{17,9,48}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{"Too short cookie string",[{auth,init_cookie,0},{auth,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,auth},{mfargs,{auth,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,5,17},{17,9,48}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,5,17},{17,9,48}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}`

I tried removing the cookie file and restarting but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the version of Erlang and the version of Ejabberd were not compatible. Once I corrected the Erlang version the problem went away. Lesson here is to make sure you are running the recommended version of erlang for your ejabberd version.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the cookie file has some content, you'll get this error if it is empty.

Comment: The cookie file contains a valid string. I also removed the cookie file and restarted to recreate it.

Comment: Looks like Erlang R14A isn't recommended for ejabberd, check the requirements section of https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/README

Comment: Thanks for finding this. Looks like the current stable erlang and ejabberd packages are not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your cookie file content here. 
May the cookie's length is really too short.

Or you can grep the source code of `erlang` for finding "too short cookie string" to check what's the problem.

## 2012/5/22, the following content added.

I have greped the my erlang source code (R15B) and found the string "Too short cookie string", only in the file "auth.erl". The related codes as follows. From the source code, your file's cookie file is empty, so the error will appear.

I think there are two way to check it.

1. You can check this by using `erlang:get_cookie() -> Cookie | nocookie` in the erlang shell.
2. You can modify the following read_cookie file by adding debugging expression for writing the detailed cookie's directory, and compile it into *.beam file and replace the old one.

**Maybe Ejabberd has used another os's user and use another's home directory's erlang's cookie file and the other cookie file content is empty. I haven't used Ejabberd before, but have faced similar problem before in rabbitmq 2 months ago.**

```
check_cookie([Letter|Rest], Result) when $\s =< Letter, Letter =< $~ ->
    check_cookie(Rest, [Letter|Result]);
check_cookie([X|Rest], Result) ->
    check_cookie1([X|Rest], Result);
check_cookie([], Result) ->
    check_cookie1([], Result).

check_cookie1([$\n|Rest], Result) ->
    check_cookie1(Rest, Result);
check_cookie1([$\r|Rest], Result) ->
    check_cookie1(Rest, Result);
check_cookie1([$\s|Rest], Result) ->
    check_cookie1(Rest, Result);
check_cookie1([_|_], _Result) ->
    {error, "Bad characters in cookie"};
check_cookie1([], []) ->
    {error, "Too short cookie string"};
check_cookie1([], Result) ->
    {ok, lists:reverse(Result)}.

read_cookie(Name, Size) ->
    case file:open(Name, [raw, read]) of
    {ok, File} ->
        case file:read(File, Size) of
        {ok, List} ->
            file:close(File),
            check_cookie(List, []);
        {error, Reason} ->
            make_error(Name, Reason)
        end;
    {error, Reason} ->
        make_error(Name, Reason)
    end.
```

Comment: The cookie length from a none working ejabberd server and a working ejabberd server are the same length.

Comment: Carlosfocker, the search result has been added to the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the file: `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`
was with more than 1 line:

```
LOBGMGERILECQBFOFTLL
#DGBDSDFTGLECQAFDCDR
```

After Remove the line with the remark i could start the service

```
cat /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
LOBGMGERILECQBFOFTLL
```

Comment: Thanks, i have no two lines but there s nothing inside erlang cookie at all.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie string must have some minimum length content and also the permission of `400`. In my case these were the issues once fixed those it worked.